# Cloud Endpoints - ImportError: No module named endpoints

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm running into this weird error with a Cloud Endpoints app that I'm just starting to write. I'm not sure if Google changed their libraries or not, but I think this should work?

In my app.yaml I've got...

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "latest"

- name: endpoints
  version: "latest"
```

And then in my main.py I call:

```
import endpoints
```

Result:

```
ImportError: No module named endpoints
```

Why would app engine be telling me that endpoints doesn't exist? I can see the endpoints folder in the directory itself...

Comment: What is your python files name?

Comment: I called it endpoints.py, but changed it back to main.py. Now I'm getting `ImportError: No module named endpoints` ... Hm... Again, odd.

Comment: you probably have not all packages completely installed.

Comment: Its strange, because I have another completed endpoints app in my SDK, which runs just fine. When I copy and paste some of the code over into the new project just as a test, I get the same `module` error...

Comment: maybe the environment pathes are not available in both setups

Comment: they should be... hm

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing on a fresh install of the SDK (previously worked).

You need to explicitly add the relevant GAE libraries to your PYTHONPATH.

For example if you're using virtualenvwrapper (you should be):

```
$ add2virtualenv /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0
$ add2virtualenv /path/to/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0
```